# dropdown menu in navigation bar not working

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I'm trying to get a drop down navigation on the right side of the navi bar, however my dropdown items are not appearing at all and my button gives me a blue line as though its a link, when hovered over.

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
 <div class="dropdown "> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar- 
 dark py-3">
    <a id="name" href="index.html">
        <img src="images/headericon.png" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top"   alt="">

    </a>
    <h5 style="font-size: 22px" class="ml-2 text-info mt-2">webname</h5>
</div>

   <ul> 
     <li><a href="#">User12345</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Favourite</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>

      </ul>
     </li>
      </ul>


     </div> 
    </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
font-family: arial;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.dropdown {
margin: 0 auto;

}



ul {
transform: translateY(-110%);
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
float: right;
margin-right:30px;


}

 ul li {

position: relative;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;


}

ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 0 15px;
color: #D3D3D3;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 60px;
font-size: 20px;

  }
ul li a:hover {
background: #494c4e;
}


ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is missing a means to display the 'open' state for the dropdown menu.

You can do this by using a :hover selector on the parent li to change its display property.

```
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

There are a few other issues with your code that you'll need to address as well.

Your HTML is invalid, I would suggest passing that through https://validator.w3.org/ to get some clues on where it's not quite right.

You're also likely to have problems with this chunk of CSS as well:

```
ul {
  transform: translateY(-110%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: right;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

You're effectively doing a `transform: translate` on all `ul` elements on the page which means it's also going to affect the position of your dropdown menu.